# What is difference between Method OverWrite and OverRide in python?

Tags: python

What is difference between Method OverWrite and OverRide in python?

I have bit confusion in concept of overwriting and overriding. suppose I have a class

```
class shape(object):
    def area(self):
        print 'Method called from shape'

class rect(shape):

    def __init__(self, h, w):
        self.h = h
        self.w = w

    def area(self, h, w):
        super(rect, self).area()
        return h + w
```

if i call super method in area method of rect it is called overriding
and if i don't call super, it is overwritting (because it is replacing)

whatever I am understanding is correct?

Comment: In my experience, *override* is used in both cases, and *overwrite* is not used in this context.

Comment: are you talking about override vs overload? I am not familiar with a term overwrite

Answer (score 1):

I have not heard of the term overwrite. the two terms that typically get confused are overload and override, but for other languages! Python does not have the concept of overloading

Overriding is replacing a parent class method with an implementation within the child class.

Overloading in other structured languages like C# or Java is creating a method with the same name, but with different parameter signatures.

you could create two distinct methods both named get_area:

```
public get_area(self, width, height){
  ...
}
public get_area(self, rectangle){
  ...
}
```

this is an example of overloading. Your example in the question is overriding. **note** overloading does not work the same in python as it does in other languages! two definitions for the same method defined within a class will not be callable. only the last implementation of the method with the given name will be callable. In the example above, if written in Python, only the get_area(self, rectangle) would be callable.

Comment: In Python, you actually can't create two *distinct* methods with the *same name* (though there are other ways to implement something like overloading).

Comment: oh interesting, python accepts both overloads, and doesn't barf, but when you try to use the first overload, it acts like it doesn't exist.

Comment: ugh, I feel like a new driver who has found the headlights for the first time after driving in the dark! thanks @ThomasOrozco

Comment: but what if i call super method in child class's method, it will also call the parent's method.

Comment: @OpenCurious what you are describing is "overriding" and calling super as you describe will call the parent class's method.

Comment: So in short there is no concept like overwritting method, it is just overriding.